# Почему плагин криптопро не обрабатывает Transform?

Tags: javascript, c#, цифровая-подпись

Пытаюсь подписать запрос для отправки в `СМЭВ` шлюз. У меня есть пример запроса, где элемент `Transforms` имеет следующий вид:

```
<Transforms>
  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
  <Transform Algorithm="urn://smev-gov-ru/xmldsig/transform"/>
<Transforms>
```

насколько я понял, режим подписания `CADESCOM_XML_SIGNATURE_TYPE_ENVELOPED` не подходит, если нужно несколько `Transform`'ов. Я стал использовать `CADESCOM_XML_SIGNATURE_TYPE_TEMPLATE`. Передаю `CPSigner`'у примерно следующий `XML`:

```
<request xmlns="http://www.bftcom.com/smevgate/">
  ...
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      ...
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
          <Transform Algorithm="urn://smev-gov-ru/xmldsig/transform"/>
        </Transforms>
        ..
      </Reference>
    ...    
  </Signature>
  ...
</request>
```

На вызове `oSignedXml.Sign(oSigner)` происходит ошибка:

> An error was encountered while processing an XML digital signature. (0x800705BA)

Убираю трансформ `<Transform Algorithm="urn://smev-gov-ru/xmldsig/transform"/>` - всё корректно подписывается. Плагин не умеет работать с этим алгоритмом? Через `Sharpei` мне до этого удалось корректно подписать.

Версия плагина `1.2.4`, версия `CSP` - `4.0.9939`, браузер `Chrome` `65.0.3325.181`

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не умеет. И на данный момент реализация этой трансформы в ближайшем времени ими не планируется.

Answer (score 0):

1. Да, если вы используете **CADESCOM_XML_SIGNATURE_TYPE_ENVELOPED**, то трансформации не надо указывать, плагин это делает сам. [Здесь](https://www.cryptopro.ru/sites/default/files/products/cades/demopage/cades_xmldsig_sample.html) вы можете посмотреть, что в результате получится.
2. Как было написано выше, плагин не поддерживает трансформацию **urn://smev-gov-ru/xmldsig/transform** (к огромному сожалению большого количества пользователей). Поэтому остается только реализовать ее самостоятельно, руководствуясь алгоритмом из "Методические рекомендации по работе с ЕСМЭВ". Глобально он сводится к удалению пробелов/переносов строк и замене namespacе'ов на ns:<порядковый номер>. [Здесь](https://toster.ru/q/501768) приведен алгоритм на PHP 7.1, но лично не проверял